# How to find mysql difference between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

Pictures and Seen_pictures, a Picture from the Pictures table is displayed to a user, that Picture (it's ID in the table) is then moved to the Seen_Pictures, and a new picture from the Pictures table is shown to the user. I need a mysql scheme that will output the difference between the Pictures and Seen_pictures table, that way I know what pictures a user hasn't seen, and can output them.

I have this so far, but it only works for 1 user, I need it to account for many different users:

```
$result = mysqli_query(
    $link, 

    "SELECT o_Pics.Pic.PicID 
    FROM o_Pics.Pic 
    LEFT JOIN o_SeenPics.Seen ON o_Pics.Pic.PicID=o_SeenPics.Seen.PicID 
    WHERE NOT o_Pics.Pic.ID='".$ID."' AND o_SeenPics.Seen.PicID IS NULL"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT p.p_id FROM Picture p WHERE p.p_id NOT IN 
   (SELECT s.p_id FROM Seen_Picture s WHERE s.u_id = "$user_id")

Picture
p_id(Primary Key) picture

Seen_Picture
id(Primary Key) u_id p_id
```

Comment: I already have primary keys in both tables, and it's just a random number I add to the db, it's not producing the correct output, put I'll keep playing with it

Comment: i'm just giving you an idea how I would construct the table. care to post your tables structure?

Comment: I got it working now I just need to work on it. I should mention that that users are the ones who add pictures the database, and each user should not be able to see their own picture, this code is showing the difference, but it's also showing that users own pictures

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make some minor modifications to your original query to get what you want:

```
SELECT s.UserId, p.PicID 
FROM o_Pics.Pic p LEFT JOIN
     o_SeenPics.Seen s
     ON p.PicID = s.PicID and
        p.OwnerUserId != s.UserId
where s.PicId is null and p.OwnerUserId != s.UserId
```

This assumes that pic has a user id of the owner in it.  It also returns the userid with the picture not seen.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't want to use "IS NULL", as I've heard that's bad.

Comment: Well, it's not, so you should unlearn that.  When there is a 1-1 match between tables, the "not in" version and left outer join version should produce similar execution plans.  In some databases, the "not in" is always implemented as a nested loop join -- which is the worst type of join.  However, it may not make a difference in mysql.